# Unknown code type during prepared command request

Tags: oracle, jdbc-odbc

My application got an error as below:
Caused by: com.inet.ora.Ora4SQLException: [OraDriver] #6 Unknown code type during prepared command request. <9>

I didn't found any detail infos on internet and i checked my db type and java type are same. Why  would it happen